# Time expression language for Java

Tags: java, dynamic, time, expression

Is there a library for Java which enables me to write time matching expressions returning true/false which I can process dynamically? Idea is to write such match expressions in properties file which are run-time loaded so I don't have to rewrite in Java in case of change-request?

Comment: i am not sure what you are asking. But see Joda Time, it is the most comprehensive Java Date Time library. http://www.joda.org/joda-time/

Comment: Am I the only one who doesn't quite understand this? Time matching? Are you talking about parsing time formats, are you talking about a language for doing comparisons between different time objects, a time equivalent of regex? Please be more specific.

Comment: Take a look at [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: cron-expression is your friend

Comment: Do you mean you need to parse "1 day 3 hours"? From which library/context does your question come from?

Comment: I all cases I would like to compare against current time. Use-case is checking if current request(whatever) is inside valid working hours.

Comment: I would like to store expresssion in properties file. For example this is expression: (current_time >= 6 and current_time < 9) || (current_time >= 12 and curren_time < 15)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as an easier solution than storing possibly complex conditions, have you considered storing a table of valid hours (or whatever unit you want to use)?

Something along the lines of:

```
6,7,8,12,13,14
```

Comment: Thanks, that's one option.

Comment: I'll use Spring's SpelExpressionParser. For example parser.parseExpression("T(java.util.Calendar).getInstance().get(T(java.util.Calendar).HOUR_OF_DAY) > 15");

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a library for Java which enables me to write time matching expressions returning true/false

Yes!

look into

```
java.util.Date
```

You have

```
public boolean before(Date when) 
public boolean after(Date when)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I would like to store expression in properties file and load it on run-time. For example this is expression: (current_time >= 6 and current_time < 9) || (current_time >= 12 and curren_time < 15)

Comment: Why not using groovy snippet and eval them in your [code](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Embedding+Groovy). There's a security risk if it's user defined code. (note that jdk 1.7 is shipped with a javascript engine)

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into that option. There's no security risk in this case because application is deployed on isolated environment.